# Knockout Js Observables

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to find definitively when you would use a ("") clear observable over just () and what the difference is. 
For example

```
self.Name = ko.observable();
```

over

```
self.Name = ko.observable("");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Gosha_Fighten's answer :

Once you write:

```
 self.Name = ko.observable();
```

you are defining an observable variable without initializing it.

Once you write :

```
self.Name = ko.observable("");
```

you are defining an observable variable and initializing it with an empty string.

later on if you use it like `self.Name()` it will return the value of it (if it is already initialized it will return that value, if not will return  `undefined`) 
Also if you use `self.Name("")` it will set that observable variable to be an empty string.

So the usage is up to you when you define it.

Answer (score 2):

`self.Name = ko.observable();` will return `undefined` if you call `alert(self.Name())` and `self.Name = ko.observable("");` will return an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When would you use one over the other?

Comment: In fact, it's the same as you use pure JavaScript `var name;` or `var name = "";`. So, the real usage depends on how you wish to use this variable further.